# Programmatically connecting a shape back to itself

Tags: c#, .net, visio

I am using the AutoConnect method to programmatically connect shapes for an export of "actions" from a database in my program. When a shape connects back to itself the AutoConnect method bombs. I was wondering if anyone has ideas on another way to accomplish this.

```
   private void connectExportedActions(DataTable dt, Page page, Document currentStencil)
    {
        List<string> Connectors = new List<string>();
        Shape parallelShape;
        Shape successShape;
        Shape unsuccessShape;
        Shape timeoutShape;
        Master connector;
        Shape timeout;
        string timeoutDisplay;


        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            Shape shape = page.Shapes.get_ItemFromID((int)row["ShapeID"]);

            if (row["acdParallelActionDefID"].ToString() != "" && row["acdParallelActionDefID"].ToString() != "NULL")
            {
                Connectors.Add("Parallel Connector");
            }
            if (row["acdPositiveActionDefID"].ToString() != "" && row["acdPositiveActionDefID"].ToString() != "NULL")
            {
                Connectors.Add("Successful Connector"); 
            }
            if (row["acdNegativeActionDefID"].ToString() != "" && row["acdNegativeActionDefID"].ToString() != "NULL")
            {
                Connectors.Add("Unsuccessful Connector");
            }
            if (row["acdTimeOutActionDefID"].ToString() != "" && row["acdTimeOutActionDefID"].ToString() != "NULL")
            {
                Connectors.Add("Timeout Connector");

            }

            foreach (string conn in Connectors)
            {

                foreach (Master mst in currentStencil.Masters)
                {
                    if (mst.Name == conn)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Action Name: {0}, ActionDefID: {1}", row["acdName"].ToString(), row["ActionDefID"].ToString()));
                        switch (conn)
                        {
                            case "Parallel Connector":
                                connector = mst; //page.Drop(mst, 0, 0);
                                parallelShape = getShape(dt, row, "ActionDefID", "acdParallelActionDefID", page);
                                **shape.AutoConnect(parallelShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirRight, connector);**
                                break;
                            case "Successful Connector":
                                connector = mst; //page.Drop(mst, 0, 0);
                                successShape = getShape(dt, row, "ActionDefID", "acdPositiveActionDefID", page);
                                **shape.AutoConnect(successShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirDown, connector);**
                                break;
                            case "Unsuccessful Connector":
                                connector = mst; // page.Drop(mst, 0, 0);
                                unsuccessShape = getShape(dt, row, "ActionDefID", "acdNegativeActionDefID", page);
                                //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Action Name: {0}, ActionDefID: {1}", row["acdName"].ToString(), row["ActionDefID"].ToString()));
                                **shape.AutoConnect(unsuccessShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirLeft, connector);**
                                break;
                            case "Timeout Connector":
                                timeout = page.Drop(mst, 0, 0);
                                timeoutShape = getShape(dt, row, "ActionDefID", "acdTimeOutActionDefID", page);
                                timeoutDisplay = "T = " + row["acdDeadlinePeriod"].ToString() + " days";
                                timeout.Cells["Prop.Display"].FormulaU = "\"" + timeoutDisplay + "\"";
                                **shape.AutoConnect(timeoutShape, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirLeft, timeout);**

                                timeout.Delete();

                                break;
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            Connectors.Clear();
        }
    }

    private Shape getShape(DataTable dt, DataRow row, string fieldname, string rowcolumn, Page page)
    {
        DataRow[] foundRows;

        foundRows = dt.Select(fieldname + " = " + row[rowcolumn].ToString());

        int ShapeID = (int)foundRows[0]["ShapeID"];

        Shape shape = page.Shapes.get_ItemFromID(ShapeID);

        return shape;
    }
```

Comment: That is a lot of text to read (and understand) and also a lot of code to read (and understand). Can you narrow the whole thing down?

Comment: Basically I am using the Autoconnect method to connect shapes together. When I try to connect a shape back to itself the Autoconnect method bombs. Is there a way to do this programmatically without using Autoconnect method?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar to what you're doing. I had prevented shapes from connecting to themselves to avoid infinite loops, but if you need to do that, the ConnectWithDynamicGlueAndConnector method from the Visio SDK code samples should be able to do it.

```
    public void ConnectWithDynamicGlueAndConnector(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape shapeFrom, 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape shapeTo) {


        if (shapeFrom == null || shapeTo == null) {
            return;
        }


        const string BASIC_FLOWCHART_STENCIL = 
            "Basic Flowchart Shapes (US units).vss";
        const string DYNAMIC_CONNECTOR_MASTER = "Dynamic Connector";
        const string MESSAGE_NOT_SAME_PAGE = 
            "Both the shapes are not on the same page.";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application visioApplication;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document stencil;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Master masterInStencil;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Shape connector;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Cell beginX;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Cell endX;

        // Get the Application object from the shape.
        visioApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application)
            shapeFrom.Application;

        try {

            // Verify that the shapes are on the same page.
            if (shapeFrom.ContainingPage != null && shapeTo.ContainingPage != null && 
                shapeFrom.ContainingPage.Equals(shapeTo.ContainingPage)) {

                // Access the Basic Flowchart Shapes stencil from the
                // Documents collection of the application.
                stencil = visioApplication.Documents.OpenEx(
                    BASIC_FLOWCHART_STENCIL,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisOpenSaveArgs.visOpenDocked);

                // Get the dynamic connector master on the stencil by its
                // universal name.
                masterInStencil = stencil.Masters.get_ItemU(
                    DYNAMIC_CONNECTOR_MASTER);

                // Drop the dynamic connector on the active page.
                connector = visioApplication.ActivePage.Drop(
                    masterInStencil, 0, 0);

                // Connect the begin point of the dynamic connector to the
                // PinX cell of the first 2-D shape.
                beginX = connector.get_CellsSRC(
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisCellIndices.vis1DBeginX);

                beginX.GlueTo(shapeFrom.get_CellsSRC(
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX));

                // Connect the end point of the dynamic connector to the
                // PinX cell of the second 2-D shape.
                endX = connector.get_CellsSRC(
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisRowIndices.visRowXForm1D,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisCellIndices.vis1DEndX);

                endX.GlueTo(shapeTo.get_CellsSRC(
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisRowIndices.visRowXFormOut,
                    (short)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.
                        VisCellIndices.visXFormPinX));
            }
            else {

                // Processing cannot continue because the shapes are not on 
                // the same page.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(MESSAGE_NOT_SAME_PAGE);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This got me thinking in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AutoConnect creates dynamic glue which you can think of as gluing to the whole shape.  But in this case you want to create static, or point-to-point glue instead.  As @bcwhims points out you use the GlueTo method of the cell object.

I'll add some code I'd written already which uses cell name syntax by way of an alternative:

```
var shpTarget = vApp.ActivePage.DrawRectangle(1.0, 10.0, 1.5, 9.5);

    shpTarget.CellsU["FillForegnd"].FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(122,201,118))";
    shpTarget.CellsU["LineColor"].FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,255,255))";

    shpTarget.AddNamedRow((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts,
                          "Top",
                          (short)Visio.VisRowTags.visTagDefault);
    shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Top.X"].FormulaU = "Width*0.5";
    shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Top.Y"].FormulaU = "Height";

    shpTarget.AddNamedRow((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionConnectionPts,
                          "Right",
                          (short)Visio.VisRowTags.visTagDefault);
    shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Right.X"].FormulaU = "Width";
    shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Right.Y"].FormulaU = "Height*0.5";


    var shpConnector = vApp.ActivePage.Drop(vApp.ConnectorToolDataObject, 1.5, 10.0);

    var beginCell =shpConnector.CellsU["BeginX"];
    var endCell =shpConnector.CellsU["EndX"];

    beginCell.GlueTo(shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Top.X"]);
    endCell.GlueTo(shpTarget.CellsU["Connections.Right.X"]);

    shpConnector.CellsU["EndArrow"].FormulaU = "5";
```

This produces the following shapes with the connectors begin/end cells showing the generated glue formulas:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is basically what I needed to get me going in the right direction. Many thanks!